# Better phrasing for "year we started working with [them]"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm making a database, establishing the fields where data is entered. The database stores a list of school systems that our company has worked with. So there's a field for the year we started working with them; but I'm drawing a blank as to how to summarize that in a small phrase.

Is there a better phrasing for the title of the field, rather than "YearWeStartedWorkingWith"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for things in computer programs is no longer within scope for our site according to our help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want a short, concise field label, correct?

How about one of these:

- Worked With Since
- Partner Since (if you consider the school systems partners)
- Since Year
- Year Started

Answer (score 1):

"Inception" means the beginning of something.

Answer (score 0):

"Engagement" is common among companies that have clients. So "year of first engagement". But your accounts-management people may consider the engagement to have commenced very precisely when (e.g.) a contract is signed. "Year of first contact" would be a little more general.